# Altium Varied Polygon Connections

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I want to change the connection rules for a few polygons in my board. for experimentation purposes I set the default rule to have direct connects on all polygons. Then created a second rule with higher priority that used thermal relief connect for that named polygon.

[image: poly itself]

[image: Rule setup]

In the end I plan on making either a class or just adding an 'OR' clause for the other polygons.

But to get to my question is that the polygon named TOP_GND_LEFT still has direct connects even after a repour.

I though maybe pour order but this poly is not on top of another?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the term "IsNamedPolygon" not "InNamedPolygon" which is what i was using above.